# How to find out when lua global value is set to nil?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I try this, but fails. __newindex is only trigger when the key has not been set.

```
setmetatable(_G, {
__newindex = function (table, key, value)
print("key: ", key, "value: ", value)
rawset(table, key, value)
if key == "Config" then
    print("value: ", value)
    if value == nil then
        error(debug.traceback())
    end
end
end})
```

Comment: You need to set a proxy table for the global table, aka `_ENV` in Lua 5.2+.

Comment: Can you show more details?

Comment: Setting proxy means using dedicated table only to capture writing/reading events. Actual data should be stored in some other table. That way you get __newindex always triggered. How to do it exactly - depends on your needs, as there's lots of ways of organizing data.

Comment: Thanks, I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Codes below work:

```
local m = {}
local t = {
    __newindex = function (table, key, value)
        m[key] = value
        if key == "Config" then
            print("config value: ", value)
        if value == nil then
            error("Config is set to nil!!!!!!"..debug.traceback())
        end
    end
end,
__index = m}
setmetatable(_G, t)

Config = Config or {}
Config = nil
```

[image]